# Ruby on Rails + Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am trying to update a div in my rails application. Iam just learning ROR. So Its a learning stage for me.Please find the code.
In view page...

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
     jQuery(function($) 
{

     $("#tabs4").click(function()
     {      
        $.ajax(
        {
        url:'/spaces/showcal',
        type:'GET'

        });
      });

});


<% end %>
```

In spaces controller..

```
def showcal

    respond_to do |format|

     format.html 
     {
      render (:update) { |page|
      page.replace_html 'tab4', :partial => 'spaces/showcal'
    }}
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here.. Please help
I also have a partials page (_showcal)which has some text to display into that div.

Comment: Anyways. Could you please tell me why should we use respond_to do |format|

     format.html format.js

Comment: The format.html and format.js is a way to respond to different response types. Perhaps you wish to render or return something a bit different depending on the format expected. If you do not have the respond_to block, your controller action simply becomes the render method call you have going, as it will just do that one step every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ajax, a good way to debug this kind of thing is see what response the server returns. If it looks good, then you know your javascript code needs to change to get it working, if it looks wrong, then fix the server side code first.

Here's how i would do it:

```
def showcal
  render :layout => false
end


#showcal.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "spaces/showcal" %>
```

Your js block:

```
jQuery(function($) 
{
  $("#tabs4").click(function()
    {      
      $.ajax({
        url:'/spaces/showcal',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data)
        {
          $('#tab4').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

I generally prefer using javascript as supposed to rails built in code when it comes to replacing and using content with ajax. I have to admit, because of this, I'm not sure if your update action was mostly correct or not.  The page.replace_html should work if you're using the prototype helpers. The only thing is because you are doing an ajax request to achieve it and the resulting body would contain that code, and it would not execute on your current dom. So i think that was probably executing, but because it's on a separate page response, it didnt do anything.

Give my suggestions a try, and let me know how it goes. Sorry that my answer is a bit hazy.

Comment: so what does the variable data contain?? Does it contain the text of partials page _showcal?? And dont we need to use respond_to do |format| in controller to check the format of the response returned?? I am sorry if I am wrong as I am just learning ROR and Jquery+ajax

Comment: the data contains whatever the response of the request is. The success function passes that data, as part of the default setup with jQuery. So in this case it will contain the partial. The format is only required if you need to respond with multiple formats for that action. Otherwise it just responds with one, and will render your html based view. For example, with a scaffold controller, in the show action, you can just have the one line `@myobject = MyModel.find(params[:id])`. The format.<whatever> is useful for things like XML or JSON responses. I use it for JSON mostly.

Comment: but when i alert the data it returned Object. In my partials page i have only 2 lines of text. So I guess those text are supposed to return if we try to alert data. Also $('#tab4').html(data) should display the text once user clicks on that tab. But it is not showing that text...

Comment: Would you mind adding the partial code to your original question so i can see it?

Comment: Have you looked at the response body of the xhr request using the nettab in firebug? Since the alert is just returning object, check to see what the server is returning to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3063/discussion-between-user662503-and-agmcleod)

Answer (score 0):

You should request `/spaces/showcal.js` and react to `format.js`.

I never worked with `$.ajax`, you might need to set additional parameters there. With script.aculo.us, something like this works:

```
new Ajax.Request('/tasks/#{task.id}.js',
    {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get'});
```